# regarding on opening a custom file in notepad++

Tags: autoit

This is my task which I am doing in AutoIT. 
Basic Info : 
I have a folder name "vk" and it has 5 subfolders named vk1 vk2 vk3 vk4 vk5.
Each Subfolder has a file ,basically a keil project.
Like

```
vk1 has first.uvproj
vk2 has sec.uvproj
vk3 has third.uvproj
```

and so on..

Now my requirement is to write a script where in the script has to go in vk1,vk2,vk3,vk4,vk5 folders
and

```
open first.uvproj in notepad++ 
Do some operation 
Close it 

Next it has to open sec.uvproj 
Do some operation 
Close it 

Next it has to open
third.uvproj 
Do some operation 
Close it and so on..
```

Till now I have done this for one file using paths hardcoded.

How to make it happen for all other folders.

Can any one help ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at _FileListToArrayRec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help file has your answer,

```
$sTextFile="first.uvproj"
Run ( "notepad.exe " & $sTextFile, @WindowsDir, @SW_MAXIMIZE )
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("This is some text.")
WinClose("Untitled - Notepad")
 WinWaitActive("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)
 WinClose("[CLASS:Notepad]")
$sTextFile="second.uvproj"
Run ( "notepad.exe " & $sTextFile, @WindowsDir, @SW_MAXIMIZE )
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("This is some text.")
WinClose("Untitled - Notepad")
```

rinse and repeat